# Is the workflow attached to the list when saved as a template?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, migration

Is the workflow attached to the list when saved as a template also copied? If yes then why is it I cannot see the workflow in SPD when i tried creating a new list based on the list template.

What im trying to do here is migrate my list-based workflow to another farm... Found this thing in here: http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/howto-move-or-migrate-sharepoint-2010-list-based-workflows-between-sites-and-site-collections/

BUT on the third step, im not able to see the original workflow... just the new created workflow...

PS: Im using sharepoint 2010

Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Did you find any solution, I have having same problem on sharepoint online.